# My new value assigned with jquery disappears after postback (UpdatePanel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have a page that showing a game list (videogames.aspx)
I have a DataGrid inside an update panel that use a usercontrol to show each videogame. (game.ascx) that is used in my videogames page.

In this usercontrol I have the ability to say progression in the game (Finish, to play etc... by using asp button)

Now I would like to have the possibility to rate a game when showing the list.
To do that I use http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/

I have created another usercontrol (for rate).
I use this usercontrol inside my game.ascx usercontrol.

When the page load for the first time I have no problem (my current rate is display)
I decide to change my rate on the first game to try and my rate is well save in the database using webmethods and well display on the sreen by javascript.

Now I decide to change my progression in the second videogame and at this moment (postback) the rating of my first game is go back to my old rating value...

I have the impression that my updatepanel keep the old value in the ViewState no?

How do I get out of this situation ?

VideoGames.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgJeux" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="dgJeux_ItemDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-Position="TopAndBottom"
    PageSize="10" GridLines="None" CssClass="table" ShowHeader="false" OnPageIndexChanged="dgJeux_PageIndexChanged">
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="paginationASP"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="jeu_id" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Jeu" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <UC:UCJeu ID="ucJeu" runat="server"></UC:UCJeu>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My game.ascx:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><UC:UCNote ID="ucNote" runat="server"></UC:UCNote></td>

    <td class="pull-right">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAvancementJeu" runat="server" Visible="false" OnItemDataBound="rptAvancementJeu_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="butAvancementJeu" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("jeuavancement_libelle") %>' OnCommand="butAvancementJeu_OnCommand" CommandName="ChangerAvancement" Width="85"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </div>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</tr>
</table>
```

My GameRate.Ascx :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#<%= noteMoyenne.ClientID %>').raty({
                score: function () {
                    return $('#<%= noteMoyenne.ClientID %>').attr('data-rating');
                },
                readOnly: true
            });
            $('#<%=noteUtilisateur.ClientID %>').raty({
                half: true,
                click: function (score, evt) {
                    var contexte = new Array('<%= noteUtilisateur.ClientID %>', '<%= noteMoyenne.ClientID %>');
                    PageMethods.AffecteNoteEtRetourneNoteMoyenne($('#<%= hfObjectID.ClientID %>').val(), score, AffecterNoteEtMoyenne, null, contexte)
                },
                score: function () {
                    return $('#<%= noteUtilisateur.ClientID %>').attr('data-rating');
                }
            });
        });
    } 
}

</script>
<table>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlNoteUtilisateur" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Note : 
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="noteUtilisateur" runat="server"></div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfObjectID" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</asp:Panel>
<tr>
    <td>
        Moyenne : 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="noteMoyenne" runat="server"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNombreNotes" runat="server" Text="(pas de note)"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Exemple of html generated by raty :

```
<div id="ctl00_content_dgJeux_ctl03_ucJeu_ucNote_noteUtilisateur" data-rating="0.5"     style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;">
<img src="../img/stars/star-half.png" alt="1" title="Beurk">
<img src="../img/stars/star-off.png" alt="2" title="Mauvais">
<img src="../img/stars/star-off.png" alt="3" title="Pas mal">
<img src="../img/stars/star-off.png" alt="4" title="Bon">
<img src="../img/stars/star-off.png" alt="5" title="Addictif">
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="0.5">
</div>
```

It use data-rating attribute to show rating value. In my case, after my new rate the value would be 3.5. My webmethod is well called and the value is save in the database. The new data-rating is changed in the html. The problem begin when I wish to change the game progression on another game. The old rate value of the first game come back after postback...

Thanks a lot for your help... I am lost

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you're updating the data-rating attribute of the div with the id ctl00_content_dgJeux_ctl03_ucJeu_ucNote_noteUtilisateur and attempting to read the modification on the server?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact I've found a simple solution. I Use HiddenField to stock my value and keep it back with jquery raty and it look nice

Comment: Just another Idea, Ajax has a nice extension for Rating as well.

Comment: Thank aRsen49 for you idea but with Ajax control toolkit I have not found how to use half star rating. Only full star